# Unsure of how some matrix equalities were arrived at?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric positive definite matrices. I came across some equalities and I don't know where they came from. I know that $$\Vert A \Vert_2 = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\Vert Ax \Vert_2}{\Vert x \Vert_2} = \lambda_{\max}(A)$$ for an SPD matrix $A$. But I don't see how that leads to the following inequalities?

1. Why does this hold: $$\lambda_{\max}(AB) = \lambda_{\max}(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})$$
2. Why does this hold: $$\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{x^TB^{1/2}AB^{1/2}x}{x^Tx} = \max_{x\neq 0}\frac{x^TAx}{x^TB^{-1}x}$$
3. Why does this hold: $$\max_{x\neq 0}\left(\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}\right) = \lambda_{\max}(A)$$

Comment: First one is a similarity transformation which preserves eigenvalues. The other two are not trivial consequences; try to prove them using the spectral theorem.

Comment: The second is a substitution

Comment: The third one follows if you suitably define $A=A^{1/2}A^{1/2}$ and note that $[\lambda_{max}(A^{1/2})]^2 = \lambda_{max}(A)$.